# How to make center the hint of searchView in android?

Tags: android-fragments

Can anyone tell how make Search View hint in centre? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Please explain clearly what do you need, what have you tried so far and paste your code in the question for others to review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the hint on the `SearchView` you need to center the gravity in the `EditText` contained in the `SearchView`.

You can find that specific view by using the Layout Inspector in Android Studio (Tools->Android->Layout Inspector). When you click on the search view in your UI, you can see it has a `SearchView$SearchAutoComplete`. That's an inner class in the `SearchView` which extends `AutoCompleteTextView`, which extends `EditText`. So, that's the view you want to change. Observe in the property-value pane of the Layout Inspector that the id is `id/search_src_text` so you can use that to get the view and center the gravity, like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(id);
if (searchEditText != null) {
    searchEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Since the id of the `EditText` isn't officially documented, there's a null check in there just in case the id changes or isn't consistent everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using androidx. Use this code

```
val searchEditText = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text) as EditText
    searchEditText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

Answer (score 2):

To center the hint and query text use a costume style for your search view :

```
<style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView" >
     <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
</style>
```

and then apply this style to your search view :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    app:theme="@style/AppSearchView" />
```

Comment: This approach worked for the alignment, but prevented my drawer layout menu to show. In my case I had to use @Danh Nguyen answer.

Answer (score 1):

For `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, use the following:

```
public static void centerHintText(SearchView searchView){
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        if (searchEditText != null) {
            searchEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed Cody's example but I would like to add onto Cody's answer above that it might actually be better to cast the found view to SearchView.SearchAutoComplete (a public static class) instead of EditText, since that's the view directly associated with R.id.search_src_text. This is to avoid any future problems if the Android team decides to swap out the inherited EditText class for another class.

See the associated view here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/search_view.xml